# Access the instance by which methods of an interface are delegated inside of the class

Tags: kotlin, delegation

Is there a way to access the instance by which methods of an interface are delegated inside of the class?

```kotlin
class Class1(): Interface2 by Class2() { // NOTE: Class2() is here a concrete implementation by which the methods of Interface2 are delegated.
  // I want to access the instance by which the Interface2 is delegated (Class2()) in here.
}
```

Fore now I do it like this:

```kotlin
private val class2Instance = Class2()
class Class1(): Interface2 by class2Instance { // NOTE: Class2() is here a concrete implementation by which the methods of Interface2 are delegated.
  val class2: Class2 by ::class2Instance // the value class2 now grants me access to class2Instance
}
```

But I don't think this is a good way, because the class has to access a value that is declared outside any class.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `Class2` a property and constructor parameter of `Class1` and then delegate by that parameter:

```
class Class1(val class2: Class2): Interface2 by class2
```

That way you do not need the reference to the `class2Interface` defined outside the `Class1` from inside `Class1`, but you have to pass it as constructor parameter:

```
val class1 = Class1(class2Instance)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I known and I would prefer not to pass ```class2Instance``` in the constructor. I could also set a default value to the constructor argument, but I would rather find another way.

Comment: You can use a private constructor to keep `class2` as a property while you expose a public constructor without argument. There is a quick working sample here:
https://pl.kotl.in/yM1lQrWdO